# Merge csv file columns and name columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, finance

I am trying to combine multiple csv files for ETF data. These csv files have the following data structure.

```
           Date     Open   High    Low  Close  Volume
0      31/12/2018  16.00  16.22  15.83  16.22  113550
1      28/12/2018  16.59  16.60  16.22  16.22  196076
2      27/12/2018  17.04  17.10  16.66  16.66   77764
3      24/12/2018  18.12  18.16  17.50  17.51  137047
4      21/12/2018  17.33  18.00  17.20  17.74  162391
5      20/12/2018  17.13  17.42  16.90  17.42  118405
```

I have used glob to read all the csv files into an array.

```
import glob
#To read all csv files
files = glob.glob('*.csv')
```

The out put of files[] looks like this.

```
['BBOZ.csv', 'CORE.csv', 'DJRE.csv', 'ETPMAG.csv', 'ETPMPD.csv', 'ETPMPM.csv', 'GOLD.csv', 'HACK.csv', 'IGB.csv', 'IJR.csv', 'IXJ.csv', 'MOAT.csv', 'MVS.csv', 'NDQ.csv', 'OZR.csv', 'SPY.csv', 'STW.csv', 'TECH.csv', 'USD.csv', 'VAE.csv', 'VAP.csv', 'VAS.csv', 'VDHG.csv', 'VGE.csv', 'VGS.csv', 'VTS.csv', 'YANK.csv', 'ZUSD.csv']
```

Each csv file is a ETF symbol

I'd like to create a dataframe that takes the ['Close'] column from each csv file and combines it into a single dataframe with the ticker symbols as each column populated by the close values for each symbols and the date as the first column

So the output looks like this:

```
Date       BBOZ CORE DJRE ETPMAG ETPMPD .... ZUSD
31/12/2018 16   17   18   19     20     ...  21
30/12/2018 16   17   18   19     20     ...  22
29/12/2018 16   17   18   19     20     ...  23
28/12/2018 16   17   18   19     20     ...  24
```

[Stock tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQsZI.png)

etc

I'm stuck on how to create that dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load your columns into a dictionary and then pass it to `pd.concat`:

```
import glob

col_list = {}
for fname in glob.iglob('*.csv'):
    base, _ = os.path.splitext(fname)
    col_list[base] = pd.read_csv(fname, usecols=['Close'], squeeze=True)

pd.concat(col_list, axis=1)
```

Comment: Coldspeed, thanks that worked
I added this in to use dates as index column
col_list[base] = pd.read_csv(fname, header=0, index_col=['Date'],usecols=['Date','Close'],squeeze=True)

Is this correct way to do this ?

Comment: Edit ** I tried to run this and it jumbles up the date column

                     DJRE    GOLD      IJR    NDQ  PMGOLD    QCB     VAP    VAS  \
01/02/2005    NaN   54.70      NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN   
01/02/2006    NaN   74.89      NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN   
01/02/2007    NaN   83.83      NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN   
01/02/2008    NaN  103.15   34.370    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN   
01/02/2010    NaN  119.00      NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN  58.47   
01/02/2011    NaN  129.90   34.500    NaN   13.40    NaN  47.182  61.10